# How to save a Sharepoint list so it can be altered or worked on later?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have created multiple SharePoint lists through InfoPath and I am having a hard time figuring out how to save a work in progress without submitting it. In other terms is it possible to save a SharePoint list as a draft when I need to come back and either alter or add to said list.

Further examples: The SharePoint list I have is a check list for creating a certain product, this check list takes me multiple days and inputs to finalize. How do I save this check list as a draft or set it aside to work on later?

Answer (score 1):

Short story, you simply can't.

What I would recommend is create a list in a test site and then migrate it once ready.